# Avoiding a legend in plotly bar chart in r

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly

In this graph [Bar chart with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBQQ9.png) I would like to hide the text that appearing into the square in the attached image.

```
p <- plot_ly(
     x = ~df1$x1,
     y = ~df1$y1,
     name = "Most frequent words",
     type = "bar",
     mode="markers" ,

color = ~df1$x1 ,
colors=c("red","blue") , showlegend = FALSE,

) %>%
layout(
    title = "Most frequent words for #Dante2018",
    yaxis = list(title = 'Frequency'),
    xaxis = list(title = 'Word', tickangle = -45))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `hoverinfo = 'x+y'` like so -

```
p <- plot_ly(
     x = ~df1$x1,
     y = ~df1$y1,
     name = "Most frequent words",
     type = "bar",
     mode="markers" ,

color = ~df1$x1 ,
colors=c("red","blue") , showlegend = FALSE,
hoverinfo = 'x+y'
) %>%
layout(
    title = "Most frequent words for #Dante2018",
    yaxis = list(title = 'Frequency'),
    xaxis = list(title = 'Word', tickangle = -45))
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much! Also, I looked for about hoverinfo and how to use with none, all, or as you indicated to me: setting specific parameters.

Comment: @rmn Glad to be of help. :) It would be great if you would consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer.